# material ui, form submission required attribute not check inside other file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui

Well I feel I'm importing wrongly, as some field - which is set to required. doesn't have the pop over "please fill in this field" when trying to submit a form.

The class:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import {SimpleFormControl} from "../SimpleFormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";


export function SimpleFormControl2(props) {
    return <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
        <FormLabel htmlFor='firstname'>Second name</FormLabel>
        <Input
            name={'secondname'}
            type={'text'}
            id={'f2'}
            autoComplete={'secondname'}
        />
    </FormControl>
}

class RegisterForm extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {submit, handleClose} = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                    <FormLabel htmlFor='firstname'>First name</FormLabel>
                    <Input
                        name={'firstname'}
                        type={'text'}
                        id={'f1'}
                        autoComplete={'firstname'}
                    />
                </FormControl>
                <SimpleFormControl/>
                <SimpleFormControl2/>
                <div style={{textAlign: 'right', padding: 8, margin: '24px -24px -24px -24px'}}>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Request"/>
                </div>
            </form>);
    }
}
```

And the imported file:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/es/Input/Input";


export function SimpleFormControl(props) {
    return <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
        <FormLabel htmlFor='firstname'>third name</FormLabel>
        <Input
            name={'thirdname'}
            type={'text'}
            id={'f3'}
            autoComplete={'thirdname'}
        />
    </FormControl>
}
```

When I test these forms the "required" asterisk is always shown. However when I try to submit, on empty first and third fields (control objects are inline or in the smae file) the "please fill in this field" popover is shown. On the second input this isn't shown, even if that is the only empty field?

Am I doing something wrong? What is happening?

---

On request, here is a sandbox test: https://codesandbox.io/s/x748rv4qz4 You can see the error by first filling out no inputs: a popover at first line. Then fill in the first line, popover at third. - then fill in the third; no popover, even though the second has been set to required and is not filled.

Comment: Currently you have two inputs that both have the id 'f2'. I would change one to 'f3' and see whether the issue persists.

Comment: @RyanCogswell good catch - I've tested and indeed it persisted (I only "comined" the test here into a single form for brevity, personal tests were with 3 different forms initially).

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: @RyanCogswell completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace:

```
import Input from "@material-ui/core/es/Input/Input";
```

with

```
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
```

it works fine.

There isn't anything wrong with using the ["es" build](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#ecmascript) if you are only targeting browsers that support it, but you shouldn't mix "es" components with non-"es" components. You're basically pulling in two copies of Material-UI which can cause a number of things to not work quite right.